# how can I change this attribute colorControlNormal programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-ktx

I couldn't change back button colour in the toolbar
But when I set this style
 `<style name="ToolbarTheme"  parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"> <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/badge_color</item> </style>`
it's working fine,
but I can't use this code because the colour comes from the API
So, how can I change this attribute "colorControlNormal" in a toolbar programmatically? or how can change back button color?

[image: the back button]

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339115/47297210)

Answer (score -1):

Change theme of Toolbar to custom theme with colorControlNormal attribute specified

Comment: It isn't possible to change the theme of a Toolbar after inflation, i.e., at runtime.